# How to set up configuration of Type ORM with .env file in Nest.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I want to set up configuration of TypeORM with **.env** file, but i have problem when I am trying to run migration script.

What i did:

**1.Added scripts to package.json**

```
    "migration:generate": "node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n",
    "migration:run": "node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert",
```

**2.Imported TypeOrmModule in app.module***

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          type: 'mysql',
          host: configService.get('HOST'),
          port: +configService.get<number>('PORT'),
          username: configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.get('DATABASE'),
          entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: true,
        })
      }
    )],
```

**3. Creaded .env file in root folder**

```
    HOST=localhost
    PORT=5432
    DATABASE_USER=dbuser
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=dbpassword
    DATABASE=dbname
```

now I am trying to run migration script like this:

```
npm run migration:generate -n AddUserTable
```

and I reciving error like this:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files.
```

According to documentation it shuld be some **ormconfig.json** but it should also working with **.env**. Please tell me, what is wrong in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error message, you should add ormconfig.json in the root project. The .env file does not relate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Check import `ConfigModule.forRoot()`. It should be imported first

You can not use forRootAsync for TypeOrmModule if you use these variables in the env file

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = postgres
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_PORT = 5432
TYPEORM_USERNAME = postgres
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = 12345
TYPEORM_DATABASE = postgres
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = false
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN = false
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/modules/**/*.entity.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = db/migrations/*.ts
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#using-environment-variables

You can also try such scripts:

```
"migration:run": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
"migration:revert": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:revert",
"migration:create": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:create",
"migration:generate": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I solved it by following the config instructions in this article, which shows you how to generate a dynamic `ormconfig.json` file:

https://medium.com/@gausmann.simon/nestjs-typeorm-and-postgresql-full-example-development-and-project-setup-working-with-database-c1a2b1b11b8f

The extra setup is a bit annoying, but it works.

Just a note if you are using typescript - the article is from 2019 and per 2020 updates to nestjs, you'll want to change the `src` paths to allow for `src` or `dist` in the `config.service.ts` file, eg. change to something like this (depending on your file structure):

```
      entities: ['**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],

      migrationsTableName: 'migration',

      migrations: ['src/migration/*.ts'],

      cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
      },
```

to

```
      entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],

      migrationsTableName: 'migration',

      migrations: [__dirname + '/../migration/*{.ts,.js}'],

      cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
      },
```

Comment: I find it completely ridiculous that my original answer was deleted by moderators bc I didn't add enough context to the link the first time. This is really helpful for those of us facing this issue. Why block it?